# Why is $PV^{(\gamma)}$ constant in an adiabatic process?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, adiabatic

I really cannot understand how to derive this expression. If possible, since I'm a beginner in calculus, I would like a simple explanation.

Edit: I don't really know where to start with my analysis.

Comment: Algebra is sufficient for this.

Comment: Let’s see your analysis so far?

Comment: @pieter Oh really.  Let’s see.

Comment: And I guess the correct relation is $PV^{\gamma}$ is constant, and, for an adiabatic *reversible* process.

Comment: https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv2openstax/chapter/adiabatic-processes-for-an-ideal-gas/